# Milight - Limitlessled Admin App not controlling Lights

Tags: c#, android, led, udpclient

I want to write an app to control LimitlessLEd lights (milight) and I'm facing an issue.

For information, I'm using VisualStudio 2017 / C#.

So far, I am able to get the SessionStart from Wifi Bridge with my Session ID1 ID2 using the code below :

```
        IPEndPoint ep = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("192.168.1.13"), 5987);
        var client = new UdpClient();
        //Connect to LimitlessLED Wifi Bridge Receiver
        client.Connect(ep1);
        byte[] LimitlessLED = new byte[] 
        { 0x20, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x16, 0x02, 0x62, 0x3A, 0xD5, 0xED, 0xA3, 0x01, 0xAE, 0x08, 0x2D, 0x46, 0x61, 0x41, 0xA7, 0xF6, 0xDC, 0xAF, 0xD3, 0xE6, 0x00, 0x00, 0x1E };
        client.Send(LimitlessLED, LimitlessLED.Length);
        var receivedData = client1.Receive(ref ep);
```

Unforutnatly, if i try to send the command to turn the Light on, i get a  suceess responce but nothing happen.

I facing also the same issue with limitlessLed admin app(v6): I got a success but noting happen, below the log from the soft.

```
Start Wifi Bridge Session...
Send UDP commands to 192.168.1.13 port 5987
Sent: 20 00 00 00 16 02 62 3A D5 ED A3 01 AE 08 2D 46 61 41 A7 F6 DC AF D3 E6 00 00 1E
Received: 28 00 00 00 11 00 02 F0 FE 6B 26 28 16 14 CA 43 76 00 01 08 00 00
LimitlessLEDWifiBridgeSessionID1 is 08
LimitlessLEDWifiBridgeSessionID2 is 00
IP Address is 192.168.1.13
MAC Address is FE:6B:26:28:16:14
Sequence Number is 02
Checksum is 3E
Sent: 80 00 00 00 11 08 00 00 02 00 31 00 00 08 04 01 00 00 00 00 00 3E
Command SUCCESSFUL.
Received: 88 00 00 00 03 00 02 00
Command completed.
```

Does anyone have an idea about it ? 
 thx in advance for your help,

cedric

Answer (score 0):

Well, just find out the problem :

Request are not exactly the same between CW bulb and WW bulb.

The limitlessLed admin app(v6) is setup for CW bulb by default but with WW Bulb the request is more like that :

```
[0x31, 0x00, 0x00, 0x07, 0x03, 0x01, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, zoneID]
```